# Fixing my questions that are completely off-topic

Tags: discussion, post-ban

Edit: I have been unbanned. I will now ask better questions.

How can I fix questions that are off-topic without replacing them with a different question (which is against the rules)?

I have been banned. My three bad questions are beyond repair. Since it is against the rules to edit them to something completely different how can I fix them? Some people are claiming I can edit them and others say I can't. Who is right?

I have 3 questions above 0, 3 at 0, and 4 below 0. Three of the four are terrible the other one is ok.

My terrible questions:

- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232616/convert-numbers-in-text-to-a-number*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36224725/advanced-title-case-javascript*
- *https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36167548/how-to-convert-a-string-to-title-case*

All I have have seen so far is fix your questions, which are against the rules to fix. Two of those questions were my first two questions. I had no idea what I was doing then. I have asked better questions since then.

My only two options seem to be creating a new account, replacing in old question completely different question, or leave SO. The first two options are against the rules but I don't have a choice but to break the rules or leave. I now understand how to ask good questions.

Comment: @user104317 _"my existing posts are beond repair unless I replace them with somehting completely different "_ Well, then you're doomed for a very long time. You may improve your profile with other positive contributions like answering or editing posts, but that seems to take a very long and stony way.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ how many questions do I have to answer?

Comment: @user104317 That's a secret. I can't tell you.

Comment: You must have deleted those questions. You seemed to have fair ones otherwise

Comment: @Drew yes I deleted them. Should I undelete them? I fear I would break my record of 9 downvotes

Comment: IIRC it was actually OK if the questions did not have answers.

Comment: @S.L.Barth by it do you mean editing the question to something completely different

Comment: @S.L.Barth if questions have multiple or upvoted answers, you simply *cannot* delete them.

Comment: Well 37232616 would be your fluke then. Surprise you did not request multi-language support as another use case :p

Comment: @Drew I was looking for a library. My use case was only in english.

Comment: @jonrsharpe True, but if the question has a single answer that hasn't been upvoted - then changing the question still invalidates an answer.

Comment: Only one of the questions has an answer. So can I edit them to something completely different?

Comment: at least 1 has an answer

Comment: Rather than blandly stating "This question is not a duplicate" (a common defense of people arguing that *their variable names are different*), you can rewrite that as a natural question. Something like "the code in xxx converts every word to Title Case, but .." And of course, any attempt of your own is highly appreciated.

Comment: .. and your third question is a plain duplicate of the second - equally badly asked. That includes the lament "but it is not a duplicate!"

Comment: @RadLexus I realize those question are terrible. How can I fix them though? It would still be off topic even if I added that (since it would need a library)?

Comment: Well, did you try to write any code at all?

Comment: @RadLexus No I was looking for a library. Which I later learned is off topic on SO.

Comment: @user104317 then expose what the problem you then had, and what you did to try and get it solved. Instead of "can I get a library to foo the bar", go "hey guys, I tried to foo the bar by doing XYZ, and I'm getting ABC.... what should I do?"

Comment: I was going to recommend editing the asking for a library out of http://stackoverflow.com/q/36167548/2564301 – but then it'd still be a duplicate. You say "every answer in the duplicate has issues". What's wrong, then, with the *very* specific answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/6475125/2564301?

Comment: @RadLexus I believe it failed for special characters like é

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question ban is not forever. If you wait long enough then you'll be able to ask questions again.

In the meantime, browse the site. You can still answer questions and suggest edits so if you find something you know the answer to provide and answer and if you see something in need of improvement, improve it.

While you are doing this you'll learn what makes a good question so when the ban is lifted and you can ask again you'll be able to ask *better* questions.

Also, remember that before you post a question you should be searching - both the site and the wider internet - to see if someone's already asked the question before you. There's a good chance that they have. That way you'll avoid posting duplicates.

Comment: Should I just create a new account and use SO over tor till my question ban gets lifted?

Comment: I always search before I post. Sometimes I miss can't find the answer even when it is there. I feel that SO marks questions as a duplicate to often. This question was closed as a duplicate of the general I have been banned question, which just says fix your questions. Then I think a moderator reopened it.

Comment: My problem is that I was looking for libraries which is off topic.

Comment: @user104317 - I can't recommend that you create a new account. If we find it we'll have to remove it as creating accounts to get around system imposed restrictions is against the rules.

Comment: How long is the question ban?

Comment: Can I replace my old questions with completely different better questions?

Comment: @user104317 - no. Replacing questions is not allowed.

Comment: So basically improve your questions which you are not allowed to improve or you will stay banned for a long time.

Comment: @user104317: You seem to think that this is unfair. Perhaps you should look at things from a less "me-centric" viewpoint. You have violated the community's quality standards. *Repeatedly*. Giving you the chance to ask more questions is unfair *to us*. You were given *many chances* to ask decent questions, and you have proven that you consider the community's standards to be optional. At some point, we have to throw up our hands and say "we're done here". That is the point you have reached. Good day, sir!

Comment: @NicolBolas Not all of my questions are terrible. Three of my questions are terrible. The rest are ok or good. I have also aswered many questions and am in the top 5% this year. Two of those question were the first to questions I asked. I was stupid then. And over time I have started asking better questions. Your comment comes across as you asked three bad questions so go away.

Comment: @NicolBolas I will leave then

Answer (score 6):

I'm not certain that there's much that can be done with your questions.

Let's start with the questions closed as a duplicate.  You're asking for the same thing in both questions and, frankly, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6475125/1079354) does a decent job of getting you started in the right direction.  Bear in mind that since Stack Overflow is an English-speaking site that you would get questions geared more towards English-structured words, phrases and capitalizations; had you added that proviso in one of your questions *and* included some sample text for others to use, it might have had a better chance of not being closed as a duplicate.

On to the question which you [outright deleted](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37232616/1079354), that's a *very* broad ask.  A way to improve this question would be to edit it and fill in what approach(es) you've attempted and where you're getting stuck.  If you're just looking to get an answer, then you're not going to get very far since not everyone has the time to dedicate to solving this approach without any prior effort by the OP.

Comment: In all three questions I way looking for a library (I now know that is off-topic). I was not exspecting someone to write an natural language for 25 reputation. I was looking for a nlp library. I was able to modify an existing title case library to solve my problem.